# Can the angular velocity of a prolate spheroid change over time in the absence of external forces?

Tags: angular-momentum, rigid-body-dynamics, moment-of-inertia, angular-velocity

Given a prolate spheroid (ie a Rugby Ball/American Football), with an initial angular velocity about an axis that coincides with one of the shape's primary axes, it seems obvious that in the absence of external forces, the body will continue to rotate with unchanging angular velocity about that axis.

However, if the initial angular velocity is about an axis that does not correspond to one of the shape's primary axes, is this still true? Or does the angular velocity change over time, eventually aligning it self with the long axis of the ball?

The reason I ask this is because in my modelling, this seems to be what happens, and I don't know if it's correct or not!

I should add that if I change the Inertia Tensor of my model to that of a sphere, rather than an prolate spheriod, I do not observe this phenomenom - in this case, the angular velocity remains constant. The code I have written is based directly on the examples given in this paper:

[https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~baraff/sigcourse/notesd1.pdf](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Ebaraff/sigcourse/notesd1.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it’s almost normal. In the reference of your ball, the angular momentum traces out a line determined by the conservation of rotational energy and of angular momentum magnitude (intersection of two surfaces).

Mathematically, writing (everything in the ball’s perspective) $\Omega,M,J$ the angular velocity, angular momentum and inertia tensor, you have $M=J\Omega$ and conservation of energy:
$$
K_{rot}= \frac{1}{2}\Omega\cdot M
$$
and angular momentum magnitude:
$$
M^2
$$
So in $M$ space, the curve is the intersection of an ellipsoid and a sphere. Check out Arnold’s Mathematical Methods for Classical Mechanics for more.

In the case of two equal principal moments of inertial (rotational symmetry about an axis like a rugbyball), then this curve is even a circle from symmetry.

In the case of a completely isotropic inertia tensor (ex: sphere) this curve degenerates to a point (two surfaces coincide as rotational energy is a function of angular momentum magnitude).

Note that rigorously from the exact conservation laws, the angular momentum (or equivalently the angular velocity) will never align itself to the principal axis unless you included friction. In this case, this is due to numerical dissipation due to your inexact solver. In general, checking conservation laws it a good test for solvers. You could also check out symplectic solvers which deal with this problem.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, at least I have some confidence that what I've got is vaguel correct. The application here is a video game, so I'm not after an exetremely high degree of accuray (the integration is a just an Euler integrator), I just want to be able to capture the movement, motion, bounce and roll of a real ball in a way that feels right.

Comment: What you say about the angular velocity not aligning to a principal axis is true - it does seem to converge on a stable axis, but that axis is not actually one of the principal ones. I'll try some damping on the angular momentumn and see what effect that has.

Answer (score 0):

Well, numerical analysis is by its nature approximation.

You describe that the model tends to slide towards a state where angular velocity becomes aligned with a principal axis.

If the model would be a perfect representation of the idealized case then the motion would *not* slide towards a simpler pattern of motion.

Example: [Feynman's wobbling plate](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AVOcgFAoFv4).
In the idealized case the wobbling pattern remains the same forever. (If the wobbling plate is in air then air friction will dissipate the kinetic energy associated with the wobbling, and the motion pattern will shift to spinning without wobbling.)

With a perfect model both angular momentum and kinetic energy are conserved. The drift that you see indicates that one of them, or both, are not conserved in the numerical analysis, presumably due to the fact that numerical analysis cannot be *exhaustively* precise. As a consequene in long runs there will be accumulation of error.

One way to mitigate drift of quantities that are supposed to be conserved is to include at regular intervals (or simply every step) a rectification. This rectification would then consist of adjusting the current velocities in such a way that quantities that you want to be conserved *are* conserved.

Presumably there are trade-offs involved with any type of numerical analysis solver.

In the other answer symplectic solvers are mentioned, which have the property of not leaving room for the conserved quantities to drift. (It may be, I don't know, that with symplectic solvers you get drift just as well, but with the drift manifesting itself elsewhere.)

The bottom line, in my opinion:
Numerical analysis comes with accumulation of error. If you let the numerical analysis model run for a long time significant accumulation of error is inevitable. I submit that numerical analysis should be used only for short runs. More precisely, the rate of accumulation of error should be assessed, then you set a limit of acceptable error, and that gives you an estimate for how long the model can be run until it has accumulated the earlier decided limit of acceptable error.

You mention:
"[...] if I change the Inertia Tensor of my model to that of a sphere, rather than an prolate spheriod, I do not observe this phenomenom - in this case, the angular velocity remains constant."

Hypothesis:
The way the numerical solver is implemented does not drift the angular veloicity if the starting motion is a particularly simple motion pattern (in this case circular motion)

That is, I expect that the difference that you have observed does not arise from a physics circumstance, but that it arises from some mathematical property of the solver implementation.

Comment: hmm, so one comment saying this is expected in real life, another that it's not!

Comment: @TomDavies Let me get the following out of the way first: in the way I wrote my reply I implied: in the idealized case the motion will not slide towards a simpler pattern of motion. The reason I focused on that: for your question the idealized case is the relevant one, since the model does not incorporate friction. As to the real world case: in the real world there is allways some dissipation of kinetic energy (be it quick or very slow), and motion *will* over time settle to a simpler pattern.

Comment: @TomDavies Incidentally, in the answer by 'lpz' there is mention of 'intersection of two surfaces'. That 'intersection of surfaces representation' is the subject of a video by Matt Parker and Hugh Hunt. They make use of a geometric representation that is called [Poinsot construction](https://youtu.be/l51LcwHOW7s)